# Simple unittest doesn't work in pycharm python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, geany

When I try to do simple unittest in pycharm, It doesn't work, the output is "Ran 0 Tests in 0.000s" and when I'm doing exactly same thing in Geany, it works, "Ran 1 Test in 0.000s" can someone figure out why?

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_cos_tam(self):

        r = '200'
        self.assertEqual(r, '200')

unittest.main()
```

```
C:\Users\wycze\Desktop\python_work\WizualizacjaDanych\Scripts\python.exe "D:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --path C:/Users/wycze/Desktop/python_work/WizualizacjaDanych/test_python_repos.py
Testing started at 23:45 ...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest C:/Users/wycze/Desktop/python_work/WizualizacjaDanych/test_python_repos.py in C:\Users\wycze\Desktop\python_work\WizualizacjaDanych
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s


OK

Process finished with exit code 0

Empty suite

Empty suite
```

Comment: My guess is that there's something wrong with how Pycharm is configured. It's a little hard to tell you any more than that because you haven't shown us the configuration. That said, you might want to try on https://superuser.com instead because this isn't a question about your code, it's a question about programs you are using (the IDEs).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel oh, you're probably right, I didn't know about this site. Thanks for answering

Comment: Does running straight `python -m unittest path/to/file/test_python_repos.py` work?

Comment: This page looks relevant: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface

Comment: I think it has something to do with specifying a file name vs specifying a module or class name.

Comment: @xdhmoore Looks like not 
```C:\Users\wycze\Desktop\python_work\WizualizacjaDanych>python -m unittest test_python_repos.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_python_repos (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'test_python_repos'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I've had similar issues in the past getting unit tests to work and I resolved them by making sure I was invoking the command from the right  directory and with the right style of module name. Here it looks to me like it doesn't like the name `test_python_repos` by itself, but I'm not familiar enough with how the module names work to be more helpful.

Comment: Another thing worth trying: `python -m unittest test_python_repos.Test`

Comment: @xdhmoore i did many simple tests like this in Geany and most of them doesnt work in pycharm, I also changed the name of `test_python_repos` but still nothing. Thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672873/356887) and some of my own test code I reformatted the folders to be:

```
C:\USERS\ME\DESKTOP\SO_TEST2
└───src
    └───test
            test_python_repos.py
            __init__.py
```

with an empty `__init__.py` file. I also added a conditional on the last line of your test file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

because I don't think you want that to run unless you run the tests directly. I'm now able to `cd` into the `src` directory and run:

`python -m unittest` with the following result:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Hopefully that is of some use to you...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem configuring Pycharm to run tests with

`Preferences/Tools/Python Integrated Tools/Testing/Default test runner = pytest.`

in your case you can set it to `Unittest`